# Extracting edge data from a networkx graph

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, utf-8, networkx

I need to extract out the edge information for each graph displayed. The data is in utf-8 form.

The graphs are displayed for each sentence in the document. So now the information from the graph has to be extracted out. The sentences to be  extracted out won't be the same as some sentences are merged in the graph. The image explains the output which has some graphs (each graph has a maximum of three nodes)

```py
for s in subject_list:
    if s is not "":
        graph.add_node(s)
        labels[s] = s


for o in object_list:
    if o is not "":
        graph.add_node(o)
        labels[b] = b

for v in verb_list:
    if v is not "":
        graph.add_node(v)
        labels[v] = v



for (s, o, v) in zip(subject_list, object_list, verb_list):
    if s and o is not "":
        graph.add_edge(s, o)
    if o and v is not "":
        graph.add_edge(o, v)

pos=nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw(graph, with_labels = True, font_family = "Nirmala UI", node_size = 40, font_size = 9 ,node_color = "darkblue")

pl.show()
g=[]
for component in nx.connected_components(graph):
    # Each component is the set of nodes
    #print(component)
    # Filter all edges in graph: we keep only that are in the component
    g=(list(
        filter(
            lambda x: x[0] in component and x[1] in component,
            graph.edges
        )
    ))
    print g

ls=[]
for x in g[0]:

    ls.append(x)
    print (x)
![connected components output][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iynw1.png
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help. In case you did not yet adress your new challenge - we do notwrite code for you, help help you fix yours. To enable us to do this, we need to know what went wrong.

Comment: How is this big blob of unicodedata relevant for your question? Can you substitute it by text we can read?

Comment: graph.get_edge_data(s,o)
s=[]
s=graph.edges()
print s       These lines give me the big blob of unicodedata. I tried to extract out the edge data but this output is the edge data for all the graphs displayed. How can I achieve the same for each graph?@PatrickArtner

Comment: Do you mean with [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))? In that case take a look at [connected_components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) of `networkx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [connected_components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) function:

```
for component in nx.connected_components(graph):
    # Each component is the set of nodes
    print(component)
    # Filter all edges in graph: we keep only that are in the component
    print(list(
        filter(
            lambda x: x[0] in component and x[1] in component,
            graph.edges
        )
    ))
```

Comment: It prints one node twice in each graph. Is there a way to eliminate what is getting printed twice? @vurmux

Comment: Because I print a component and edges in a component. Just remove the first `print`, for example.

Comment: I have removed the first print. But one node information is repeated twice. The node that is common is printed twice.@vurmux

Comment: [(केल्यो, सगळ्यांत चड ४५ धांवड्यो ),(शिखर धवनान ,सगळ्यांत चड ४५ धांवड्यो)]  Output of one component .सगळ्यांत चड ४५ धांवड्यो is repeated twice .

Comment: Most of your nodes has two edges to neighbours and will appear in `edges` list twice (one for each neighbour edge).

Comment: I'm trying to print the text from utf8 to Devanagari but I'm unable to do it for the entire list. Can you please check this @vurmux

Comment: In connected components , can the edge order be specified?@vurmux

Comment: Basically no, it is a set. But you can convert it into a list and sort it after.

Comment: How do we count the number of nodes in each connected component?@vurmux